# cannot be cast to org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I wrote so code:

```
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
    ...
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                "test/BeanConfig.xml");
        LocalSessionFactoryBean localSessionFactoryBean;
        localSessionFactoryBean = (LocalSessionFactoryBean) context.getBean("sessionFactory");
```

I saw:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl cannot be cast to org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean
    at com.epam.hhhsystem.services.UtilMethods.createTestDb(UtilMethods.java:21)
    at com.epam.hhhsystem.services.UtilMethods.main(UtilMethods.java:31)
```

BeanConfig.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <!-- Включаем опцию использования конфигурационных аннотаций (@Annotation-based configuration)-->
    <context:annotation-config />


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.epam.hhsystem.jpa" />

    <!-- Файл с настройками ресурсов для работы с данными (Data Access Resources) -->
    <import resource="data.xml" />

</beans>
```

data.xml

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

<!-- Настраивает управление транзакциями с помощью аннотации @Transactional -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <!-- Менеджер транзакций -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Непосредственно бин dataSource -->
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
        p:driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
        p:url="jdbc:sqlserver://10.16.9.52:1433;databaseName=hhsystemTest;"
        p:username="userNew" 
        p:password="Pass12345" />

    <!-- Настройки фабрики сессий Хибернейта -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:test/hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop> 
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.epam.hhs</groupId>
    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.9-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>hhsystem core</name>
    <!--<packaging>war</packaging> -->

    <properties>

        <!-- Generic properties -->
        <java.version>1.6</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <spring-framework.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>
        <spring-data-jpa.version>1.3.2.RELEASE</spring-data-jpa.version>
        <org.springsecurity-version>3.1.3.RELEASE</org.springsecurity-version>

        <!-- Java EE / Java SE dependencies -->
        <jsp.version>2.2</jsp.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
        <servlet.version>2.5</servlet.version>
        <jaxb-impl.version>2.2.7</jaxb-impl.version>

        <!-- Hibernate / JPA -->
        <hibernate.version>4.2.1.Final</hibernate.version>

        <!-- Bean validation -->
        <hibernate-validator.version>4.3.1.Final</hibernate-validator.version>

        <!-- Database access -->
        <tomcat-jdbc.version>7.0.37</tomcat-jdbc.version>
        <ehcache.version>2.6.6</ehcache.version>
        <hsqldb.version>2.2.9</hsqldb.version>

        <!-- AOP -->
        <aspectj.version>1.7.2</aspectj.version>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>

        <!-- RSS -->
        <rome.version>1.0</rome.version>

        <!-- Test -->
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
        <hamcrest.version>1.3</hamcrest.version>

        <!-- Dates -->
        <jodatime-hibernate.version>1.3</jodatime-hibernate.version>
        <jodatime-jsptags.version>1.1.1</jodatime-jsptags.version>
        <jodatime.version>2.2</jodatime.version>
        <jadira-usertype-core.version>3.1.0.CR6</jadira-usertype-core.version>


        <!-- Web dependencies -->
        <webjars-bootstrap.version>2.3.0</webjars-bootstrap.version>
        <webjars-jquery-ui.version>1.9.2</webjars-jquery-ui.version>
        <webjars-jquery.version>1.9.0</webjars-jquery.version>
        <dandelion.datatables.version>0.8.14</dandelion.datatables.version>

        <mysql.version>5.1.22</mysql.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-http</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${jstl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servlet.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jsp.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${jaxb-impl.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- SPRING, SPRING, SPRINGITY SPRING -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-data-jpa.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- used for EhCacheCacheManager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Database connection pool See here for more details on commons-dbcp 
            versus tomcat-jdbc: http://blog.ippon.fr/2013/03/13/improving-the-performance-of-the-spring-petclinic-sample-application-part-3-of-5/ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat-jdbc.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- For MySql only -->
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>mysql</groupId> <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId> 
            <version>${mysql.version}</version> </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>mysql</groupId> <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId> 
            <version>${mysql.version}</version> </dependency> -->
        <!-- HIBERNATE -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-validator.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.25</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Webjars (static dependencies distributed as JAR files) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>${webjars-bootstrap.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${webjars-jquery-ui.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>${webjars-jquery.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test Artifacts -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- used by Spring MVC Test framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
            <version>${hamcrest.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springsecurity-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springsecurity-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springsecurity-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ow2.easybeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>easybeans-uberjar-eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0-M1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <!-- Maven plugin versions are mentioned in order to guarantee the build 
        reproducibility in the long term -->
    <build>
        <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <!-- declared explicitly so Spring config files can be placed next to 
                    their corresponding JUnit test class (see example with ValidatorTests) -->
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/java</directory>
            </testResource>
            <testResource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <Xlint />
                    </compilerArguments>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.13</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warName>petclinic</warName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                    <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                    <sourceIncludes>
                        <sourceInclude>**/*.*</sourceInclude>
                    </sourceIncludes>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildCommand>
                            <name>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</name>
                        </buildCommand>
                        <buildCommand>
                            <name>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Builder</name>
                        </buildCommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</projectnature>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                        <projectnature>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Nature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <server>tomcat-development-server</server>
                    <port>9966</port>
                    <path>/petclinic</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

How to fix it?

Comment: have you tried without casting?

Comment: Pratik, I added pom.xml in question topic

Comment: ZaoTaoBao, Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to LocalSessionFactoryBean

Comment: @gstackoverflow --> M. Deinum has written a great explanation, tell us if is the reason, i'm really intriguited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `LocalSessionFactoryBean` is a `FactoryBean` is basically creates an object of another type. In this case a `SessionFactory`. You cannot lookup the `LocalSessionFactoryBean` the way you are doing as this will result in a `SessionFactory` instead. (Which is also probably what you want and not the factory).

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("test/BeanConfig.xml");
SessionFactory localSessionFactoryBean context.getBean("sessionFactory", SessionFactory.class);
```

If you really want the `FactoryBean` itself prefix the name with `&` which will give you the actual `FactoryBean` instead of the result/creation of the `FactoryBean`.

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("test/BeanConfig.xml");
LocalSessionFactoryBean localSessionFactoryBean context.getBean("&sessionFactory", LocalSessionFactoryBean .class);
```

Links

1. Factory Bean explained in the [reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-extension-factorybean)
2. FactoryBean [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/FactoryBean.html)